# .htaccess adding php type

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-php

i been tring to add .inc page as php page using .htaccess, but each time i add it to my existing code in the end of the line, it downloads the page rather then process as a php file.

my existing .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on

Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteBase /

#RewriteRule (mp3|mp3/)$                    audio/qari.php  [L]

RewriteRule mp3/(.*).mp3        audio/$1.mp3    [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)(\.)(.*)$      $1$2$3          [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$              /index.php      [L]
<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>

deny from 67.218.116.130
```

i tried adding following line in the existing code, but dont work.

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .inc .php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .inc .php
```

Comment: I think you need to put the code on .htaccess instead of your apache config

Comment: head to add 5 init - AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .inc

Answer (score 0):

Try AddHandler instead of AddType

Alternatively try

```
AddHandler php5-script .php .html .inc
```